# How can I get my component to calculate the sum of checkbox values in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-props

This application renders a list of foods with checkboxes next to them. I have a component that should calculate and display the sum of the checkbox values when they're checked. I am not able to display the values from the checkboxes.

This is currently what I have.

This file renders a list of foods with checkboxes next to each.

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, Accordion } from "react-bootstrap";

const Cards = props => {
  return (
    <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
      <Card>
        <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey={`${props.key}`}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            value={props.calories}
          />{" "}
          {props && props.title + " : " + props.calories + "cal"}
        </Accordion.Toggle>

        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={`${props.key}`}>
          <Card.Body>
            {" "}
            {props.obj.nutrients &&
              "fat: " + props.obj.nutrients["fat"]} ||{" "}
            {props.obj.nutrients &&
              "trans fats: " + props.obj.nutrients["transfat"]}
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>{" "}
    </Accordion>
  );
};

export default Cards;
```

I would like for this component to do the sum with the value from input box which is "props.calories" in the Cards component. This is what I've tried so far.

```
import React from 'react';
import Cards from './card';


class Calculator extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isChecked:false
        };
        this.handleChecked = this.handleChecked.bind(this);
    }

    handleChecked() {
     this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked});
    }



    render() {
            var total;
            if (this.state.isChecked) {
                total += <Cards.input.value/>;
            } 

        return (
            <div>
            <h1>Total: {total}</h1>
            </div>


        );
    }
}


export default Calculator;
```

I'm brand new to React and any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: checkboxes have two values, either 1 or 0

Comment: So I would be able to do this https://codepen.io/poto228/pen/jbyxNJ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that there are multiple mistakes in the example given above. It is expected since you are new to React and JSX thing sounds like an alien concept initially.

I have reproduced the scenario what you are looking for:

[`https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-uctkj`](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-uctkj)

Hope it helps !

Feel free to drop in a comment if you do not understand something in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want different component to calculate value. You can just use state of the Card component to calculate. Moreover `<Cards.input.value/>;` doesn't seem right. If you are passing value in props than use `props. <your prop >`

Comment: I've done it multiple ways." total += <Cards.input.value/>;" was my final attempt